# Android- Saving entries in a checklist as a file to be viewed later

Tags: android, list, checkbox, save, scrollview

I have created an app with multiple activities, each of which containing a list of checkboxes that each contain a certain when check. The app takes the view of the layout, on the click of a button, and adds the values of the checked boxes and displays a value. I was wondering if there is a way to save the state of the checklist as a file once the button is clicked,  so that it can be viewed later. The file should display the checklist and show which boxes have been checked or have remained unchecked. I have already tried saving it as an image, but since the list is contained within a ScrollView and the screen of my phone is pretty small, only the part of the list that is visible on the screen is captured. I want to ultimately be able to open the file on a computer and convert it into an excel spreadsheet, but that does not have to be in the code.

Here is my Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InputsActivity extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.inputs);
     }

     public void DisplayScore(View view){
          float score= (float) Math.round(CalculateScore(view)*10)/10;  
          Toast.makeText(InputsActivity.this,"Input score is " +score+"%.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     private double CalculateScore(View view) {
          double percent=  (AddChecks(view) + 2)*100/12;
          return percent;
     }

     private double AddChecks(View view) {
          double sum=0;
          for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
               String checkId="value" + i;
               int resID= getResources().getIdentifier(checkId,"id","com.example.ARTHChekclist");
               CheckBox check= (CheckBox) findViewById(resID);
               if (check.isChecked()) {
                     sum++;
               }
          }
          return sum;
     }
}
```

This is my xml layout

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />

         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/value10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />
         <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checkbox1" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Submit"
             android:onClick="DisplayScore" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to save data to file.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

The file itself is an XML, and you can easily view it later and even convert to anything you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would it be easier to use a SQlite Database and save the responses in a table?

Comment: if you have unknown number of checkboxes - DB will be better, since you can iterate easily over a table with all the values.
But if you have fixed number of items, it might be easier to just use SharedPreferences, avoiding the whole process of creating a DB and interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use shared prefs as Udinic suggests. something like this should work...

```
SharedPreferences storedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storedPrefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("YOUR_TAG", true);

        editor.commit();
```